# (numpy/scipy) Build a random vector given mean vector and covariance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, random-sampling

After running several calculations with numpy, I end with the mean vector and covariance matrix for a state vector. Is there a way with numpy or scipy to sample a random vector around this mean and covariance?

Comment: if your variables are normal, then look at `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If random vector $X$ has variance $S$, then $LX$ has variance $LSL^\top$.

So generate whatever random variables with mean 0 and identity covariance matrix, then transform it $LX+\mu$, where $\mu$ is your mean vector and $LL^\top$ equals to your covariance matrix. You can find $L$ by cholesky decomposition.